# Update a table based on the existence of a row in the subtable?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a bit confusing to explain, but basically I've got a parent table `fruits` and a child table `fruits_sub`, which references `fruits` via a foreign_key `fruits_id`.

fruits:

| fruits_id | enum_0_col | enum_1_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |

fruits_sub:

| fruits_id | enum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |

The existence of a row in `fruits_sub` is the source of truth and tells us whether or not the corresponding enum column should be enabled in the `fruits` table. For example, if we look at the rows with `fruits_id` of 1 in `fruits_sub`, there are two entries with a `enum` of 0 and 1. This means that in `fruits`, both `enum_0_col` and `enum_1_col` should be enabled (set to a value of 1). However, `enum_0_col` is incorrectly set to 0, so I'd like to update the table and set it to 1. `fruits_id` of 2 is missing altogether in the `fruits_sub` table, which means in `fruits`, the row should have both `enum_0_col` and `enum_0_col` set to 0, and i'd like to update the table to reflect that.

This is a query I have tried to figure out which entries have "mismatches" for the enum of 0:

```
CASE 
    WHEN
        NOT EXISTS ( SELECT fruits_id FROM fruits_sub
        WHERE enum = 0 )
    THEN
        SELECT * from fruits 
        WHERE fruits.fruits_id = fruits_sub.fruits_id
        AND fruits.enum_0_col = 1
    WHEN
        EXISTS ( SELECT fruits_id from fruits_sub
        WHERE enum = 0 )
    THEN
        SELECT * FROM fruits
        WHERE fruits.fruits_id = fruits_sub.fruits_id
        AND fruits.enum_0_col = 0
END
```

And then I have a similar query for the enum of 1. I am seeing a syntax error with the above query, i'm guessing maybe because I can't do a select clause on two different tables

Comment: What queries have you actually attempted so far?  It would be useful if you posted them here, then someone would be able to provide assistance with where you might currently be going wrong.  If you haven't attempted any queries yet, then a good place to start with this sort of thing is to first build a SELECT statement that displays only the records that you know need to be updated, based on the relevant criteria.  That SELECT statement will then form the basis for your UPDATE statement, so that you can achieve your desired end result

Comment: On a separate note, having this sort of data (that is, separate tables of what should be the same data, that can become "disconnected" from each other) is never really ideal.  What is the particular use case behind the table structures like this?  Perhaps your desired end result could be achieved using a view over your "fruits_sub" table, that outputs the relevant enum values - rather than relying on two separate tables that you can't guarantee will always be in sync with each other

Comment: Updated the original post to show a query I have tried. Sadly yes I agree this table setup isn't ideal, but it's what I have to work with. My task is to go back and fix up the data entries that have gotten out of sync.

Comment: Yeah, you've got a whole lot of wrong stuff going on in that query example ... you haven't closed the brackets on your EXISTS, and CASE doesn't really work that way, having a SELECT * FROM ... statement after THEN.  Some research into those query element would be useful

Answer (score 0):

To keep the "fruits" table in sync with the "fruits_sub" table, you will - in reality - need to:

- Update existing rows to reflect the correct enum values
- Add new "fruits" rows, for any "id" that exists in "fruits_sub", but not in "fruits"
- Delete any existing "fruits" rows where the "id" does not exist in "fruits_sub"

(I've kept these relatively simple for now, so hopefully you can easily discern exactly what is happening at each of the steps)

Delete existing "fruits" rows (where there is no corresponding "fruits_sub" row) first:

```
DELETE FROM fruits 
WHERE fruits_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT fruits_id FROM fruits_sub
)
```

Insert new rows (enum values default to zero first, then will be updated):

```
INSERT INTO fruits
SELECT
   fs.fruits_id, 0, 0
FROM fruits_sub fs
LEFT OUTER JOIN fruits f
   ON f.fruits_id = fs.fruits_id
WHERE f.fruits_id Is Null
```

UPDATE existing "fruits" rows, depending on the existing of "fruits_sub" enums:

```
UPDATE f
SET enum_0_col = 
CASE
   WHEN EXISTS
   (
      SELECT 1 FROM fruits_sub fs
      WHERE fs.fruits_id = f.fruits_id
      AND fs.enum = 0
   )
   THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END,
SET enum_1_col = 
CASE
   WHEN EXISTS
   (
      SELECT 1 FROM fruits_sub fs
      WHERE fs.fruits_id = f.fruits_id
      AND fs.enum = 1
   )
   THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END
FROM fruits f
```